# Scala plugin installed but not shown in creating new project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I downloaded/upgraded the latest IntelliJ IDEA 2019.02 from 2017.x, I had Scala plugin installed already in the previous IntelliJ 2017, and I can see it also gets automatically upgraded.

[image]
however, when I create a new project, I do not see the plugin showing up in the left panel:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is gone after Scala plugin is upgraded.